# this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function / this.form.get is not a function in reactive form array in angular 14

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular14

I am trying to create a formarray with already specified number of formcontrols but i am not able to bind it with the html form.

my form is as below:

```
`this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
               'indicator' : this.formBuilder.array([
                      {'accessLevel' : '0'},
                      {'accessLevel' : '0'}
               ]),
          });
`
```

html:

```
`<div class="row" formArrayName="indicator">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="form-label">Sale</label>
    <div class=" field-checkbox d-block mb-0" [formGroup]="addForm.value.indicator[0]">
        <p-radioButton name="accessLevel"  value="001" formControlName="accessLevel"></p-radioButton>
        <label>Yes</label>
        <p-radioButton name="accessLevel" value="0" formControlName="accessLevel" class="ms-4"></p-radioButton>
        <label>No</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="form-label">Buy</label>
    <div class="field-checkbox d-block mb-0" [formGroup]="addForm.value.indicator[1]">
        <p-radioButton name="accessLevel" value="002" formControlName="accessLevel"></p-radioButton>
        <label>Yes</label>
        <p-radioButton name="accessLevel" value="0" formControlName="accessLevel" class="ms-4"></p-radioButton>
        <label>No</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `indicator` `FormArray` should contains `FormGroup` instance(s) instead of the object(s).

```js
this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  indicator: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({ accessLevel: '0' }),
    this.formBuilder.group({ accessLevel: '0' }),
  ]),
});
```

2. For your nested form group(s), use `formGroupName` attribute and provide the index.

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="indicator">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="form-label">Sale</label>
    <div class="field-checkbox d-block mb-0" formGroupName="0">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="form-label">Buy</label>
    <div class="field-checkbox d-block mb-0" formGroupName="1">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9arfz?file=src/app/app.component.html)